# The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page "~/Views/Shared/index.cshtml"

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page "~/Views/Shared/index.cshtml"

An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

how to fix this error

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 22):

In my case after I add

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer><p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

to the shared layout's footer, all worked perfectly. this occurs because of the layout page on

> **view -> shared**

haven't load the method `@RenderBody()` so you can either get rid of this using the upper code fragment or you can just comment the layout at the top of your relevant cshtml page.

Answer (score 3):

please put this code just before "body" close tag at the end of your page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

The “RenderBody” method has not been called for layout page

This typically occurs when you:
– have a partial view
– use a _ViewStart.cshtml page
– you call the partival view from your controller using: return View();

And there you go wrong. It is a partial view, so you should return like this:

return PartialView();

Source : http://www.cloud-developer.eu/blog/2014/01/20/renderbody-method-called-layout-page/

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, my case is I use a nesting layout, you need to include @RenderBody for all _layout

read here for detail: https://forums.asp.net/t/2098873.aspx?The+RenderBody+method+has+not+been+called+for+layout+page+Views+Shared+_Layout+cshtml+

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error until i released I accidentally left a `return;` call before the page got to the `@RenderBody()` line.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error when i was working on TagHelperComponent in my asp.net core MVC project. I googled a lot but everyone had a different problem than mine and obviously had a different solution than mine such as multiple layout files etc. Let me explain my problem -

i was making a CopyRight TagHelperComponent for injecting my copyright content (just before the body closing tag) into each and every view of my application like below -

```
public class CopyRightTagHelperComponent:TagHelperComponent
{
    public CopyRightTagHelperComponent(string copyrightContent)
    {
        CopyrightContent = copyrightContent;
    }

    public string CopyrightContent { get; set; }

    public override Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (context.TagName.Equals("body", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            output.Content.AppendHtml(CopyrightContent);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

but you can find the problem in my above code pretty well i believe. The problem is, i was trying to inject my copyright content in body tag (means not before the body closing tag, but with the Content property) by mistake. After spending a lot time, i observed that i used "Content" property to append my content instead of PreContent or PostContent property and that's what my mistake.

Cause of error was only, i was trying to append content with "Content" property. Changing my below line code from "Content" to "PostContent", error fixed -

```
if (context.TagName.Equals("body", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
   output.PostContent.AppendHtml(CopyrightContent);
}
```

Important Node: By default, Tag Helper Components only operate on head & body elements.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/65af12f1f575fdaee893e0232416df29bb83d7fa/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/TagHelpers

To make them working for other elements like Footer, we need to create a new Tag Helper (named FooterTagHelper in case of footer element) which will derive from special class "TagHelperComponentTagHelper". For reference, see below code from Microsoft -

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/65af12f1f575fdaee893e0232416df29bb83d7fa/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/TagHelpers/BodyTagHelper.cs

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer to this, I had the same problem and to fix it very EASY!, go to your view folder create _viewSrart.cshtml - then go to each view you have inside the views folder and delete or comment this ( Layout = "~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml";)  it will work. thank me later